# Swift - Prototype Cell get value from TextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with 2 prototype Cells.

The first Prototype Cell has a TextField and Button on the right. Let's say it "Cell1"

The second Prototype Cell has only a label. Let's say it "Cell2"

I just want to type something in the first cell and then by taping the Button to :

1) Create a new Cell2 Prototype Cell Row

2) That new Cell2 Prototype Cell Row must have a Label with the value i entered on the Cell1 TextField.

So with that way i could have a list of Cell2 Rows with different values of TextField.

**I know how to achieve the first (the new Row created) but not the second.**

When the segue starts, i have only the Cell1 Prototype like this photo :[image: Here segue starts]

And when i tap the + Button, i have a new Row of "Cell2" Prototype.
This kind of Cell must have the label of the Textfield everytime.[image]

How can i take the value of TextField everytime and pass it to new created Cell2 Row Label?

Comment: So do that. What is the question?

Comment: My question is that i cant do the second that i describe. Any idea?

Comment: Sure, I know how I would do it. How are you doing it?

Comment: I am creating the new row (Cell 2 Prototype) by appending a new String value (Textfield.text) to an Array everytime user tap the Button. Then the the func tableView (numberOfRowsInSection) creates a now row because returns the Array.count. But i cant figure out how to pass everytime the TextField text.

Comment: It sounds good so far. Just keep in mind that your array indexes must correspond to the row indexes of the table. That way, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation will know how to set the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all probability your difficulty is merely that your data model is a little too simple-minded. Keep in mind that all the work must be done by your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation consulting the data model. Thus the data model must know two things for each row:

1. Is this a prototype 1 row or a prototype 2 row?
2. What is the text field (if this is a prototype 1 row) or label (if this is a prototype 2 row) value for this row?

Given a data structure that carries that information, it is clear enough how to proceed:

- As the user types in a text field, the text field delegate should enter the text field's text into the model at that row.
- When the user hits the Plus button, we figure out what row this is and insert into the data model, immediately after the current row, a new entry marked as a prototype 2 row with the same text value as the current row. We then insert the row into the table as well, so that our `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for the new row.

Given those simple instructions, it's quite easy to build a working example of the sort of thing you're trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Added a screencast showing that my instructions do actually work! :)